# How to output the minimum number through Heapsort but not destory the structure of the heap？

Tags: java, heapsort

When I am doing some code in the website of hackerranker, there is a problem saying that you must use the heapsort and output the minimum number of an `ArrayList` given by the console, but you shouldn't destroy the structure of the tree or the heap.

I think it's easy but I don't have an idea of how to solve it? So please help me.

Comment: Show some code, we have no idea what kind of structure you are using, or algorithm, or anything.

Comment: `I think it's easy but i don't hava the idea that how to solve it` huh?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to use heapsort algorithm to sort a ArraryList and then output the minimum element?

The first step is to build a [binary-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) that takes the form of a binary tree. And then you should maintain this structure any time you extract an element.

What doesn't make sense is to use heapsort. If you build a min-binary-heap, the root element is already the min element of the Array.